# sql query reserves symfony

Tags: sql, symfony

Here are my entities:

```
Reserves    
id<br>
user<br>
treat_type<br>
from_date<br>
number<br>
price<br>
hour (manyToOne with ReserveTime -> time)<br>

ReserveTime<br>
id<br>
time<br>

my query: <br>
$em = $this->getEntityManager();<br>
    $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT rt.time<br>
              from reserves r, reserve_time rt<br>
              where r.hour = rt.id and r.from_date = :date_reserve 
and<br> r.number < 2");<br><br>
$stmt->execute(array("date_reserve" => $reserve_date));<br>
return $stmt->fetchAll();<br>
```

I want that when user pick a date to get all available hours for that day, but it only give me the result with the hour of the reserve with that day. I want all hours not only the hour that is in that reserve. 
I hope you can help me thanks.

Comment: Please format your code when asking questions. This looks messy and makes your question less likely to get an answer in many cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select all entities of the given day. If the $reserve_date is a DateTime object then:

```
$startDate = clone $reserve_date;
$startDate->setTime(0,0,0);

$endDate = clone $startDate;
$endDate->modify('+1 day');

$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT rt.time from reserves r, reserve_time rt where r.hour = rt.id and r.from_date > :from_date and r.from_date < :to_date and r.number < 2");

$stmt->execute(array("from_date" => $startDate, "to_date" => $endDate));
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

After that you have to loop through the results and find the free time-windows.